# Magento, Redirect my old urls to Magento urls

Tags: magento, url, redirect

I already finished my Magento website, now I need to redirect all old website urls to Magento url pages, is that can be done.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://kb.magenting.com/content/10/9/en/change-magento-base-url.html

Comment: Hi shivam, and thank you for reply, I already did that, but the old sit main is directing but other pages are not, how to redirect all old site pages

Answer (score 0):

Just go to phpmyadmin database  of that site ,which you want to redirect to your site and run below query in your sql.

replace http://www.site.com/ with your main site url

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://www.site.com/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/%/base_url';

Comment: Remember to vote up my answer ,if you need further help comment here.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, in fact both old and new site in the same root folder domain, and the old urls is different than new ones, is your solution will work?

Comment: this is old url: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/contents/fr/d114.html and this is new url: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter, but it is must to be the old site is magento site..because the query which i have given is for magento database.if not then you will use htaccess redirect.

Comment: old site is not Magento site

Answer (score -1):

1. if you have access to database, open it.
2. open core_resource table
3. Change value for:

   web/unsecure/base_url

and

```
web/secure/base_url
```

Delete **/var/session** and **/var/cache** folder.

Refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks mohit for the answer, but I didn't find "core_resource table" in web/unsecure/base_url

Comment: Thanks Emi, you are correct, the only problem is I don't have the details of editing the .htaccess file and make some 301 redirects

Comment: I think they deleted my previous comment, don't know why. Try this, where BASE_URL has the value of your Magento's base_url. But you would have to match all of your old urls, that means you will have a line for each old url.
RedirectMatch 301 /old-url BASE_URL/new-url
Editing the .htaccess file would be the fastest way. Otherwise I think you can add them from Magento Admin > Catalog > Url Redirects